# How to define my own version of filter procedure in racket?

Tags: filter, racket

I am new in Racket and I was assigned to do **my own filter** procedure. It should work similar to the Racket filter procedure. Currently, my-filter has two arguments: the even procedure to check the items in the list, and a list of items.

So far, I have been only able to check whether the items in the list are even or not. my-filter is supposed to iterate through a list of numbers, retrieve the numbers that are even and save them in a second list. How can I iterate through the list and store the even numbers in the second list?

```
(define (my-filter f lst)
  (if (empty? lst) 
     empty 
     (cons 
        (f (first lst)) 
        (my-filter f (rest lst)))))
```

```
> (my-filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
'(#f #t #f #t #f #t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases that you need to consider:

- Input list is empty -> we're done.
- Current element satisfies the predicate function -> add it to the output and continue with next element.
- Current element doesn't satisfy the predicate function -> skip it and continue with next element.

You're mixing the last two cases into a single case. And notice that you must not add `(f (first lst))` to the output, that's just the condition that we want to evaluate, we should add `(first lst)` instead. This is what I mean:

```
(define (my-filter f lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) empty)
        ((f (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter f (rest lst))))
        (else (my-filter f (rest lst)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(my-filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '(2 4 6)
```

Comment: Another view to look at this is that there are only two cases: the input is an empty list, and the input is not an empty list. For the latter case, you have two more subcases: the first element satisfies the predicate, and the first element doesn't satisfy the predicate.

Comment: Thank you so much Óscar, it makes more sense now. And, also thanks Sorawee, that is another way to see too.